# Graph editor, handle lengths are extremely long. Is there a easy way to fix that?

Tags: keyframes, graph-editor, fcurves

In graph editor, key handles are too long or too short. It creates bad curves. I adjust them manually and it takes so much time. Is there another way to do that. And is it normal to have such handles, curves? Or I just mess something up?

Thank you.

[image]